# Save of form in database

Tags: python, django

I try to fill in a standard form. Only the saving of the model does not work. It then changes to the default error page on save ().

The error says:

```
'WohnungHinzufuegenForm' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What could be the mistake?

urls.py:

```
    path('user/ereignis/wohnungHinzufuegen', views.wohnungHinzufuegen,name="wohnungHinzufuegen"),
```

models.py:

```
class Wohnungseinheiten(models.Model):
    wohnungsnummer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    strasseHausnummer = models.CharField("strasseHausnummer",max_length=100)
    adresszusatz = models.CharField("adresszusatz",max_length=100)
    plz = models.CharField("plz",max_length=100,blank=True)
    ort = models.CharField("ort",max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def wohnungHinzufuegen(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form4 = WohnungHinzufuegenForm(request.POST)
        if form4.is_valid():
            #Here he definitely goes in and fills in the test variables: 
            tmpadresszusatz=form4.cleaned_data['strasseHausnummer'] #contains values
            tmpadresszusatz=form4.cleaned_data['adresszusatz'] #contains values
            try:
                form4.save() #this doesn't save -> it shows the default error page then
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(str("done."+e)) #returns never
            return HttpResponse(str("done."+tmpLogin +"|"+tmpPassword))
            return redirect('user/ereignis')
```

forms.py:

```
class WohnungHinzufuegenForm(forms.Form): 
    strasseHausnummer = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    adresszusatz = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100)
    plz = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    ort = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = Wohnungseinheiten
        fields = ('strasseHausnummer','adresszusatz','plz','ort')
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: 'WohnungHinzufuegenForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` class does not implement `save()` method. You need `ModelForm` class.

```
class WohnungHinzufuegenForm(forms.ModelForm): # forms.ModelForm instead of forms.Form
    strasseHausnummer = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    adresszusatz = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100)
    plz = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    ort = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Wohnungseinheiten
        fields = ('strasseHausnummer','adresszusatz','plz','ort')
```

Hope, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Only based forms "ModelForm" have a built-save method. For forms based on "Form", you have to create a save method.